# Fitting a plane with the Prewitt gradient operator

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, least-squares, computer-vision

**Prewitt gradient operator**

Show that the Prewitt gradient operator can be obtained by fitting the least-squares plane through the 3 × 3 neighborhood of the intensity function.

Hint: Fit a plane to the nine points (x + $\delta$x,y + $\delta$y,I[x + $\delta$x,y + $\delta$y]) where $\delta$x and $\delta$y range through −1, 0, +1. Then, having the planar model z = ax + by + c that best fits the intensity surface (i.e. minimizes the least-squares error in the z-direction), show that the two Prewitt masks actually compute a and b.

**Solution**: We denote the nine points by ($x_j$,$y_j$,$z_j$), $j$ = 1,...,9. The least-squares error for the planar model is:
$$
\epsilon(a,b,c) = \sum_{j= 1}^n(ax_j, + by_j + c + z_j)^2\tag{1}
$$
By differentation we get
\begin{align*}
\nabla\epsilon &= \begin{bmatrix}
\sum_{j= 1}^n(ax_j, + by_j + c + z_j)x_j\\ \sum_{j= 1}^n(ax_j, + by_j + c + z_j)y_j\\
\sum_{j= 1}^n(ax_j, + by_j + c + z_j)
\end{bmatrix}\\\tag{2}
\end{align*}
by setting the gradient to zero
$$
\implies=\begin{bmatrix}
\sum_{j = 1}^nx_j^2&\sum_{j = 1}^nx_jy_j&\sum_{j = 1}^nx_j\\
\sum_{j = 1}^nx_jy_j&\sum_{j = 1}^ny_j^2&\sum_{j = 1}^ny_j
\\
\sum_{j = 1}^nx_j&\sum_{j = 1}^ny_j&n
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
a\\
b\\
c
\end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix}
\sum_{j = 1}^nx_jz_j\\
\sum_{j = 1}^ny_jz_j\\
\sum_{j = 1}^nz_j
\end{bmatrix}\tag{3}
$$
For our 3 $\times$ 3 neighborhood we may fix the coordinate origin at the center of the mask. In this case $x_j$ and $y_j$ range through −1, 0, +1 and the normal equations have the form
$$\begin{bmatrix}
\color{blue}6 & 0 &0 \\
0 & \color{blue}6 & \color{red}9\\
0 & 0 & \color{blue}9
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
a\\
b\\
c
\end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix}
\sum_{j = 1}^nx_jz_j\\
\sum_{j = 1}^ny_jz_j\\
\sum_{j = 1}^nz_j
\end{bmatrix}\tag{4}
$$
Therefore the optimal plane is obtained by
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a\\
b\\
c
\end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{6}\sum_{j = 1}^nx_jz_j\\
\frac{1}{6}\sum_{j = 1}^ny_jz_j\\
\frac{1}{9}\sum_{j = 1}^nz_j
\end{bmatrix}\tag{5}
$$
where the first two components are obtained by using the Prewitt masks:
$$
M_x = \begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 0 & 1\\
-1 & 0 & 1\\
-1 & 0 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}, \quad 
M_y = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0\\
-1 & -1 & -1\\
\end{bmatrix}\tag{6}
$$

**My questions**

- In (4), where do the $\color{blue}6$, $\color{blue}6$ and $\color{blue}9$
- In (4), shouldn't the $\color{red}9$ be a $\color{red}0$ instead?
- How can we get the insight between (5) and (6) (the relation with Prewitt mask)?

Comment: In (4), the red 9 is out of place. It should be in the bottom right. As for the origins of these numbers: Remember that the $x_j$ and $y_j$ are $-1,0,+1$.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @WolfgangBangerth. So from your comment I understand that $\color{red}9$ should indeed be a $\color{red}0$. For the origins of the $\color{blue}6$, $\color{blue}6$, $\color{blue}9$, could you develop a little bit the steps needed between the fact that $x_j$ and $y_j$ are -1, 0, +1 and the obtention of the matrix in (4)?

Comment: Think about the first entry. You're adding 9 numbers $x_j^2$. These are the 9 $x$-coordinates of the origin and the 8 points with integer coordinates that surround it. Of these, 3 points have $x_j=-1$, 3 points have $x_j=0$, and 3 points have $x_j=+1$. So adding up $x_j^2$ yields 6 times 1 plus 3 times 0. That's 6.